# Apache Kafka - is it possible to lose messages on error?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm digging into [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) with [Spring Cloud Stream](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) and observed some behavior that makes me wonder if I'm doing something wrong or if it is working as intended - which I hardly doubt:

It is possible to lose messages on error!?

My setup is as simple as possible. A single Kafka broker and a topic with only 1 partition. Broker, topic, producer and consumer with default settings (auto-ack is true).

**testcase 1**

- produce `message1`
- produce `message2`
- start a consumer that will throw a RuntimeException on receiving **any message**
- consuming `message1`, retry
- consuming `message1`, retry
- consuming `message1`, retry
- exception is thrown
- consuming `message2`, retry
- consuming `message2`, retry
- consuming `message2`, retry
- exception is thrown
- stop and restart the consumer
- consuming `message1`, retry
- consuming `message1`, retry
- consuming `message1`, retry
- exception is thrown
- consuming `message2`, retry
- consuming `message2`, retry
- consuming `message2`, retry
- exception is thrown

Works as expected.

**testcase 2**

- produce `message1`
- produce `message2`
- start a consumer that will throw a RuntimeException on receiving **exactly `message1`**
- consuming `message1`, retry
- consuming `message1`, retry
- consuming `message1`, retry
- exception is thrown
- successfully consuming `message2`
- produce `message3`
- successfully consuming `message3`
- stop and restart the consumer
- nothing happens, the consumer waits for new messages to consume

`message1` will be skipped because the commited offset has been set to `message3`. This is what troubles me. I don't want the consumer to continue with messages as long as prior messages were not successfully processed.

Has anyone experiences the same behavior and/or maybe could guide me on how to change this?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update:** as requested, some code snippets

Create the topic

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test-topic
```

Connect a producer

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-topic
```

Create a maven project with

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

...

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Add the following `application.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: test-topic
          contentType: text/plain
          group: test-group
          consumer:
            header-mode: raw
      kafka:
        binder:
          zkNodes: localhost:2181
          brokers: localhost:9092
```

Add the following `Application.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    private void consume(Message<String> message) {
        log.info("Received: {}", message.getPayload());
        if ("message1".equals(message.getPayload())
            throw new RuntimeException();
        log.info("Successfully processed message {}", message.getPayload());
    }
}
```

That should be it. Run the application and use the console-producer to produce messages.

Comment: if there is only one partition, why would the consumer consume message2 when failed to consume message1 in testcase2?

Comment: @herokingsley I've no idea but that is what is happening. If it wouldn't consume `message2` after the failed attempts with `message1` then I would be satisfied.

Comment: maybe show us some code or log will be helpful

Comment: @herokingsley I've added some code snippets to my question.

Comment: And how does the code for testcase1 looks like?

Comment: @Arek remove the if clause, everything else is the same

Answer (score 0):

Kafka gives you a runtime, but you have the power of choice. In some scenarios msgs can be lost/skipped, in some may not - you need to prepare the configuration according to your needs. IMO you should investigate further some of Spring Cloud Stream settings. You can also play around with disabling auto commits and commiting offset "by hand".

Comment: I'll give manual commits a try but I hardly can believe that the behavior I've described would be ok for most scenarios. By default `message1` should block `message2` until successfully processed (and thus acknowledged) and if you don't want blocking then you would have to change the configuration - but that is just me, maybe I don't get the big picture right now.

Comment: Just disabling auto-commit is not enough. You need to keep track of acknowledged messages and manually check if the message that is about to be processed is the next in line prior to processing it. That is absolutely not satisfying for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka each message comes with an offset id. Your consumer application can keep a check on offset, and if any offset is skipped or missed instead of consuming the next message. you can use **consumer.seek** method get the specific message which is missing.

Offsets are incremental in nature and sequential.

And in your case use manual commit.

I could say use the below steps..

1. After poll method, first check the previously committed offset and
   and request the next offset value
2. Once message is  consumed and processed successfully, save the
       offset value of successfully processed message in some internal
       memory or table.  During next poll

The below link will not serve your usecase, but you can get fair idea

Refer [Example](https://github.com/Viyaan/KafkaProducerConsumer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kafka/consumer/CustomPartitionerConsumer.java)

Comment: stphngrtz is not using native Kafka API

Comment: I agree, but SCS provides a lot of abstraction. Anyway you are right, that self managing offset is one of options.

Comment: If I decide to put messages into a specific partition that is most likely because I want them to be processed in order of occurance. I don't think that it is a very unique requirement to not want messages to be skipped that easy. In some scenarios that may be the case but then please provide some kind of configuration option to change the behavior. Anyway, from my point of view I'd like the not-skipping behavior to be the default.

Comment: The steps you suggest would work but, to be honest, I can't believe that's what the guys from kafka and/or spring want us to do. In a distributed system with several different services or instances of the sames service I don't want to keep track of who has successfully processed which message. I want kafka to do this for me.

Comment: There are frameworks like storm, spark which does it for you.. but Will spring lib does is something need t see the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure a DLQ for such cases. If your message could not be consumed after 3 retries, it's most likely it won't be consumed at all  or it needs special treatment.
Set a DLQ where the poisonous message could land, and you won't loose messages

Comment: But moving `message1` to a DLQ would break the ordering, right? The thread would continue with `message2` after moving `message1` to the DLQ.

Comment: It won't break the ordering. It's not like message2 was consumed before message1. But unless you want to stop all consumption of messages on error, and therefore not committing offset, this is what happens in any message oriented system. Error messages are sent to a special place and the flow continues. Otherwise on any error the system would stop